# Running sample ROS node on Android through SL4A

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Following the instructions in section 6 on running the sample ROS node on android page http://www.ros.org/wiki/android, when I went to SL4A, then went into ros.py, it asks for the ROS_PACKAGE_URI. I filled in the field with http://ubuntu:11311/. Then it says "uname: permission denied". How can I go about this?

Thanks

Soe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10204/running-sample-ros-node-on-android-through-sl4a./) by [soetommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/442/soetommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2011-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you considered using rosjava instead? You'll see much better integration with Android that way. See http://rosjava.googlecode.com/

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-06-23**:
They are part of the Android library and not part of rosjava.jar. If you're having trouble, this may be better off as a separate question.

**Comment by [soetommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/442/soetommy/) on 2011-06-22**:
There is currently a problem with importing RosTextView and MessageCallable into the java because they seem not to be included in the rosjava.jar library.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-06-22**:
There are fully functional Android projects under trunk/android/tutorials.

**Comment by [soetommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/442/soetommy/) on 2011-06-21**:
Hi Damon, Yes, I have already tried it, but cannot seem to understand how to start it off. Can you provide some simple example source files for linking android with ROS, which are fully functional? That would be very helpful indeed. I am using the eclipse with android sdk and adt tools. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Soe,

this should not affect negatively the functionality of the sample ROS node or any other Android ROS nodes.

**Background:** *roslib/os_detect.py* tries to detect the current operating system the ROS node is running on. *uname* is called during these OS checks. However, on *un-rooted* Android devices *uname* cannot be called due to missing permissions. For this reason, the error occurs in the terminal.

Best regards,
Stefan

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Diewald](https://answers.ros.org/users/666/stefan-diewald/) with karma: 11 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3